# Node JS Child Process argument is invalid

Tags: node.js

ok so here is my code im not sure what the problem is because if i manually type node start.js username:pass@proxy.com:22225 it works fine. Thanks in advance

```
const cp = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')
const proxies =['username:pass@proxy.com:22225','username:pass@proxy.com:22225','username:pass@proxy.com:22225']
var sleep = require('sleep')
var maxproxies = 30
for (let i = 0; i < proxies.length; i++) {
    var child = cp.fork("./index.js", proxies[i]) 
    console.log('Proxy '+ i+1 + ' loaded')
    sleep.sleep(5)
}  
but when i load it errors with this
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'arguments[1]' is invalid. Received 'username:pass@proxy.com:22225'
?[90m    at Object.fork (child_process.js:73:13)?[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\smkam\Desktop\test\start.js:7:20)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m {
  code: ?[32m'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'?[39m
?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second param of `child_process.fork` is an array, but you provided a string.

Comment: but proxies[i] is an array?

Comment: so shouldnt     var proxyParsed = JSON.parse(proxies[i]) work then

Comment: `proxies` is an array, `proxies[i]` is one of `'username:pass@proxy.com:22225','username:pass@proxy.com:22225','username:pass@proxy.com:22225'`, it's a string.

Comment: You can try this:
```
var child = cp.fork("./index.js", [proxies[i]]);
```

Comment: it responsed the same as my code var proxyParsed = JSON.prase(proxies[i])
error code 

undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0
the 1 is referring to my proxy url

Comment: What's `JSON.parse` use for?

Comment: i have a question is it possible to add a 3rd arguement?

Comment: @MylesK According the [nodejs fork doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), you can.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it i simply created an empty array push the proxies from the array once every loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < proxies.length; i++) {
    var proxy = []
    proxy.push(proxies[i])
    var child = cp.fork("./index.js", proxy);
    console.log('Proxy ' + i + 1 + ' loaded')
    sleep.sleep(5)
}
```

Comment: `var child = cp.fork("./index.js", [proxies[i]]);` is a better choice.